# Text Field and Labels are not visible in tableViewCell of UITableVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was following the Storyboards tutorial iOS7 form raywenderlich.com .
When I was using the storyboard adding Label and Text Field to table view cell(static cell) , they just cannot be seen . Hope these two pictures helped explain the situation.[Text Field when editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXmA.png) and [disappear at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9pJl.png) .

I also used NSLog() with the methods that send and recieve the contents in the Text Field, and find out that the data was correctly passed.

Occasionally,I found a way to solve the problem. Just embed the Text Field or the Labels in a view inside the Content View. Then they worked well.
But I still don't know why this happened and why "editor->embedin->view "would work.

Comment: Labels are visible as far as I see. Are you sure that you set the constraints right?

Comment: Is AddPlayer a TableViewController?

Comment: @Abhinav I think so.

Comment: try using size class for Compact width and Regular height

Comment: @EminBuğraSaral     How to set the constraints? Use auto layout or something?  I'm sorry I just begin the programming ting.

Comment: @Johnykutty  You mean use auto layout?

Comment: I believe your textfield is already there, just tap on that to see if keyboard shows up.

Comment: @Abhinav  You are right.The textfield is there.And keyboard shows up too.but the text is not visible.

Comment: Which text not visible... when you type something using keyboard?

Comment: @Abhinav yes, I also put a NSLog( ) in the method  'done' to check if the text was typed in. So it was there ,but I can't see it.

Comment: Check the frame of your text field... Just for the sake of testing try keeping it in middle of cell and keep width as short as to fit one word and then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text field is there on UI. It's just that it does not have border and placeholder so it is not visible.

Tap on that to see the keyboard appearing!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have two pictures to show the problem. The text field dose have a placeholder "????".    And after tap on the text field,the keyboard appeared but the text I typed in wasn't.

Comment: Check if your text color is same as that of text field background color. So, it may be typing in there but you can't see it.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the "editor->embedin->view "would work?After I embed the text field in a view, it is visible.

Comment: Probably view background color is contrasting with text color. Your issue is not visibility of text field but visibility of text.

Comment: Finally, It worked. I set the background color of content view from 'default' to 'white color' , then I can see the text.  It seems the content view's default background color cause this issue?  I still have no idea why this happened.

Comment: Awesome ... Need to dig that. Can this answer be accepted now?

Comment: Hey @Facecat any reason you de-accepting this answer.

Comment: sorry,network wasn't well .  maybe I double click it.

Comment: I thought so ... no problem :)!